# Why is there a single backlash which doesn't even continue with the pyramid?

Tags: java, eclipse

The assignment was to create a pyramid by using `for` loops, `print` and `println` functions. I wrote the following code, though without errors, the last backslash is one character before where it should be. There should be five slashes/backslashes on the sides of the pyramid.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
       for ( int i = 0; i <5; i++) {
           if ( i < 4) {
               for ( int a = 4 - i; a > 0; a--) {
                   System.out.print(" ");
               }
               System.out.print("/");
           }
           for ( int a = 2 * i; a > 0; a--) {
               System.out.print(" ");
           }
           System.out.println("\\");
           }
       }
```

The output should be like in

[image]

But it turns out like

[image]
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you include the output in your question instead of linking to them?

Answer (score 0):

The print for '/' is in the wrong place - it should be outside of the `if`:

```java
for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  if ( i < 4) {
      for ( int a = 4 - i; a > 0; a--) {
          System.out.print(" ");
      }
  }
  System.out.print("/");
  for ( int a = 2 * i; a > 0; a--) {
      System.out.print(" ");
  }
  System.out.println("\\");
}
```

But you don't actually need that `if`, the `for` loop condition will deal with not printing a blank on the last row:

```java
for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  for ( int a = 4 - i; a > 0; a--) {
      System.out.print(" ");
  }
  System.out.print("/");
  for ( int a = 2 * i; a > 0; a--) {
      System.out.print(" ");
  }
  System.out.println("\\");
}
```

And, just for fun, if you are using Java 11 or later you can replace the inner loops with the `repeat` method of `String`:

```java
final int limit = 5;

for (int row = 0; row < limit; row++) {
  System.out.println(" ".repeat(limit - (row + 1)) + '/' + " ".repeat(2 * row) + '\\');
}
```

But that is probably not how you are expected to do this assignment.

Comment: I didn't know that `String::repeat` method for Java11, that's nice :)